# Get the amount of days between two given days of the week

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

I want to find out how many days there are between two given days of the week.

This looks to be a case for a well executed [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method; but I just can't get my head around it.

```
const days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday']

let today = 'Thursday'
let dispatch = 'Monday'
let remaining = '???'

console.log(`${remaining} Days until the next dispatch`)
```

Monday to Thursday is easy enough :

```
let remaining = days.slice(days.indexOf('Monday'), days.indexOf('Thursday')).length + 1
```

But Thursday to Monday (for example) needs some logic that I can't figure out.

Comment: What will be output of the Thursday to Monday `4` or `5`

Comment: Should the number include the current day? So would Monday to Thursday be 3 days or 4? For me it should be 3. As Monday to Tuesday should be 1 and Monday to Monday should be either 0 or 7 (your scheme doesn't allow to express the difference).

Comment: @PaulRooney and MaheerAli... It shouldn't include the given day. So Monday to Thursday would return 3 days. And Thursday to Monday would return 4 days.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can drop the slice and the if and make use of some modulo arithmetics.

```js
const days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday']

function getDays(start, end) {
    return (days.indexOf(end) + days.length - days.indexOf(start)) % days.length + 1;
}
console.log(getDays("Monday", "Thursday")); // 4
console.log(getDays("Thursday", "Monday")); // 5
```

If you decide you want Monday to Thursday to just be 3 instead of 4 (which might be more natural depending on the context) just drop the +1 from the end.

Comment: @Akrion, my function is fine but you are calling it with 3 arguments whereas mine only takes 2. Try `console.log(getDays('Saturday', 'Friday'))`.

Comment: Yeah my bad. Need more coffee :/

Comment: Thanks for this @NikolaDimitrof. An elegant solution to a simple problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can directly subtract two `.indexOf()` values without calling `.slice()`, no? Like this:

```js
const days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday']

let today = 'Thursday'
let dispatch = 'Monday'
let remaining = days.indexOf(dispatch) - days.indexOf(today) + 1
if (remaining < 1) {
    remaining += days.length
}

console.log(`${remaining} Days until the next dispatch`)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `reverse` the array if the order is reversed.

```js
const days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday']

let today = 'Thursday';
let dispatch = 'Monday';
let reversed, remaining;
if (days.indexOf(today) > days.indexOf(dispatch)) {
  reversed = days.slice().reverse();
  remaining = reversed.slice(reversed.indexOf(today), reversed.indexOf(dispatch)).length + 1;
} else {
  remaining = days.slice(days.indexOf(today), days.indexOf(dispatch)).length + 1;
}

console.log(`${remaining} Days until the next dispatch`)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `slice` function, here's a way of achieving your goal:

```js
const getRemaining = (arr, start, end) => {
  let startIndex = arr.indexOf(start);
  let endIndex = days.indexOf(end);
  if (startIndex > endIndex) {
    // We should go to beginning
    endIndex += arr.length;
  }
  return endIndex - startIndex;
};

const days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];

console.log('Thursday to Monday: ', getRemaining(days, 'Thursday', 'Monday'));
console.log('Monday to Thursday: ', getRemaining(days, 'Monday', 'Thursday'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```js
const days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday']

let getDayDistance = (days, from, to) => {
  let f = days.indexOf(from), t = days.indexOf(to)
  return f < t ? (t - f) : (days.length - f) + t 
}

console.log(getDayDistance(days, 'Monday', 'Thursday'))   // 3
console.log(getDayDistance(days, 'Thursday', 'Monday'))   // 4
console.log(getDayDistance(days, 'Sunday', 'Saturday'))   // 6
console.log(getDayDistance(days, 'Saturday', 'Friday'))   // 6
console.log(getDayDistance(days, 'Thursday', 'Tuesday'))  // 5 
console.log(getDayDistance(days, 'Wednesday', 'Sunday'))  // 4
console.log(getDayDistance(days, 'Friday', 'Tuesday'))    // 4
```